# Excel VBA Json Converter to table

Tags: json, excel, vba

I've been trying around with the VBA JsonConverter.

Hi have a json that looks like this:

```
{
    "payload": {
        "c": {
            "aa": "value_aa",
            "bb": "value_bb"
        },
        "k": {
            "aaa": "value_aaa",
            "bbb": "value_bbb"
        },
        "o": {
            "oa": "hallo",
            "odid": [
                "121",
                "222"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The result should look like this:

```
parameter   value
payload.c.aa    value_aa
payload.c.bb    value_bb
payload.k.aaa   value_aaa
payload.k.bbb   value_bbb
payload.o.oa    hallo
payload.o.odid1 121
payload.o.odid2 222
```

This is the best I've been to at the moment.
The list isn't like the result I like to have. The parameter is missing and the value isn't in the correct column. I is surely just a bit. But I don't see where I can fix this

```
Sub jsonListToExcel(jsonObject As Object, sheet As Worksheet, row As Long, col As Long)
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    With sheet
        For Each element In jsonObject
            .Cells(row + i, col).Value = element
            i = i + 1
        Next element
    End With
End Sub

Sub jsonToExcel(jsonObject As Object, sheet As Worksheet, row As Long, col As Long, parentKey As String)
    For Each Key In jsonObject.Keys
        If TypeName(jsonObject(Key)) = "Dictionary" Then
            jsonToExcel jsonObject(Key), sheet, row, col, parentKey & "." & Key
        ElseIf TypeName(jsonObject(Key)) = "Collection" Then
            jsonListToExcel j

sonObject(Key), sheet, row, col
            Else
                If Left(parentKey & "." & Key, 1) = "." Then
                    sheet.Cells(row, col).Value = Right(parentKey & "." & Key, Len(parentKey & "." & Key) - 1)
                Else
                    sheet.Cells(row, col).Value = parentKey & "." & Key
                End If
                
                sheet.Cells(row, col + 1).Value = jsonObject(Key)
                row = row + 1
            End If
        Next Key
    End Sub
    
    Sub Test1()
    Dim jsonText As String
    Dim jsonObject As Object
    
    Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    
    
     jsonText = "{""payload"":{""c"":{""aa"":""value_aa"",""bb"":""value_bb""},""k"":{""aaa"":""value_aaa"",""bbb"":""value_bbb""},""o"":{""oa"":""hallo"",""odid"":[""121"",""222""]}}}"
        
    
     Set jsonObject = JsonConverter.ParseJson(jsonText)
    
    jsonToExcel jsonObject, ActiveSheet, 1, 1, ""
    End Sub
```

And this should be completely independent by the Keys.
Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another parameter `key` to `jsonListToExcel`

```vb
Sub jsonListToExcel(jsonObject As Object, key, sheet As Worksheet, row As Long, col As Long)
    Dim i As Integer, element
    i = 1
    If Left(key, 1) = "." Then key = Mid(key, 2)
    With sheet
        For Each element In jsonObject
            .Cells(row, col).Value = key & i
            .Cells(row, col + 1).Value = element
            i = i + 1
            row = row + 1
        Next element
    End With
End Sub
```

and the call

```vb
 jsonListToExcel jsonObject(key), parentKey & "." & key, sheet, row, col
```